# java bounded generic type definition for several types

Tags: java, generics, types

I'm trying to write a generic method that works for numeric types and for string types. Is there a way to have a bounded type like this

```
<T extends Number || String> void print(){...}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you just use method polymorphism?

Answer (score 2):

Better solution will be to have two overloaded methods:

```
T void print(<T extends Number> number) {}

void print(String s) {}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had thought of this, just didn't want to write the same method twice))

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The only way that a type definition can be declared for "several types" is if those types share a common ancestor in the inheritance hierarchy, or if they implement the same interface(s). Both `Number` and `String` are of type `Object` and implement `Serializable`, but that's all they share in common.

Besides, in your example what's the use of the generic type? the method doesn't receive any parameters and doesn't return anything. Maybe you're better off overloading the `print` method, like this:

```
void print(String s) {}
void print(Number n) {}
```

Comment: Not that it helps here, but you can actually declare as many interfaces as you want in your type parameter: `T extends ClassFoo & InterfaceA & InterfaceB`. In this case, any `T` would have to be a subtype of ClassFoo, InterfaceA *and* InterfaceB, and it would have an erasure of ClassFoo.